# Wooden puzzle/game - 16 dowels with five wooden balls with holes each

Tags: game, puzzle-identification

I acquired a wooden puzzle game from a local thrift store. They had no information about it. Here's a description:

In a wooden board base are mounted 16 dowels on each of the dowels are 5 wooden balls with a hole in each. 1/2 the balls are of a darker wood & 1/2 are light colored wood 1 dowel on each only has 4 balls. What might be the name of this puzzle/ game and how do you play it?

Answer (score 5):

That's 3D four-in-a-row. You play by alternately placing a ball on a dowel (at most four per dowel) until one player has four balls of their color in a row, vertically, horizontally or in any of 10 diagonal directions.

Comment: Thanks! That is the Correct answer! I looked it up on ebay, using your term and found it! I seem to be missing 2 lake though. I will see if I can acquire the rules as well.

Comment: If this answer satisfactorily solved your question, please upvote it (click on the higher voting arrow) and Accept it (click on the checkmark under the voting arrows). This will mark the answer as helpful and the question as solved.